# Wordpress orderby child pages

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to list child pages of the current page with the most recent first but I can only get it to show in alphabeticl order. Setting orderby isn't making any difference.

```
<?php
global $post;
$currentPage = $post->ID;
// Get posts (tweak args as needed)
$args = array(
        'child_of' => $currentPage,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $posts = get_pages( $args );
    foreach (array_chunk($posts, 1, true) as $posts) :  ?>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <?php $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image_or_video', true)); ?>
        <?php $video = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'embedded_video', true); ?>
        <?php $alt_text_for_logo = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'article_name', true); ?>
        <?php $short_description = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'article_short_description', true); ?>
        <?php if( $img || $video ): ?>
        <div class="column small-4 medium-4 large-4 card white margin-bottom"> 
            <div>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php if( $img ): ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $img[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt_text_for_logo; ?>" />
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if( $video ): ?>
                        <?php the_field('embedded_video'); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                    <p><?php the_field('article_short_description'); ?></p>
                    <p class="tag"><?php echo get_the_title( $post->post_parent ); ?></p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation [page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages), you should use:

`'sort_order' => 'asc',
'sort_column' => 'date',`

Answer (score 1):

set `sort_order` to **desc** and `sort_column` to **ID**

```
$args = array(
        'child_of' => $currentPage,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'sort_column' => 'ID',
        'sort_order' => 'desc'
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the WordPress Query: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters
You need to change the query like this:

```
$args = array(
    'child_of'  => $currentPage,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'orderby'   => 'date',
    'order'     => 'DESC'
);
```

I hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

Remove `'orderby' => 'rand',` and make `'order' => 'DESC'` that should solve your issue.

so the argument $args will be

```
$args = array(
    'child_of'  => $currentPage,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'orderby'   => 'ID'
    'order'     => 'DESC'
);
```

or you can use post_date

```
$args = array(
    'child_of'  => $currentPage,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'orderby'   => 'post_date',
    'order'     => 'DESC'
);
```

Comment: Hi, I had tried orderby date but it wasn't working so I tried rand to be sure.

Comment: @RReveley have you check codex it is `date` or `post_date` ?